# Redirect user to a web page on uninstall uwp application

Tags: c#, redirect, uwp, uninstallation

I search a solution that until the user uninstall my UWP application he will be redirected to a specified page on the web.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the package uninstall event:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.packagecatalog.packageuninstalling?view=winrt-18362

Then you can open a link with the browser in your handler.

Comment: Thank you . Have you an example haw to use it ?

Comment: @Oussemaf Hello, you can add this code in the constructor of `MainPage` or `App`: `PackageCatalog c = PackageCatalog.OpenForCurrentPackage(); c.PackageUninstalling += C_PackageUninstalling;`, and then use the automatic suggestion of Visual Studio to add the `C_PackageUninstalling` event processing method.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's help me